# Use page.type on only numeric input fields

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to fill out a form on a webpage using Puppeteer, but there are some input fields that only accept numeric input, like:

```
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric">
```

But I can't write to these Input fields with page.type like I do with normal Input fields. When I try it I get the error message:

```
TypeError: text is not iterable
```

On all other inputs, page.type works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurred because you are trying to invoke `page.type()` function with a number instead of the string type.

`page.type(selector, text[, options])`

- selector `<string>` A selector of an element to type into. If there are multiple elements satisfying the selector, the first will be used
- text `<string>` A text to type into a focused element.
- options `<Object>`

  - delay `<number>` Time to wait between key presses in milliseconds. Defaults to 0.
- returns: `<Promise>`

For instance:

```
await page.type('#mytextarea', '123')
```

or you can set value with `eval` function:

```
await page.$eval('selector', field => field.value = 12);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the perfect answer to my problem! :)